# In Windows Explorer mouse sometimes not releasing a click

Tags: drivers, windows-explorer, mouse

Kinda weird issue that seems to be limited only to working with windows explorer. Sometimes when I click on a file, it will not 'release' the click so it will start drawing the selection box as if I was holding down the button. It is not a hardware issue, the button is not stuck and only happens when dealing with files/folders in explorer.

I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling mouse drivers, no change.
i guess its acting like a little clicklock (which is not enabled)
mouse is wired btw

Comment: I do not see this very often (although I have seen exactly as you describe).  Try new batteries in the mouse and restarting the machine.

Comment: wired, no batteries

Comment: Please do a shut down, startup and see if the issue remains. If so, try a different mouse.  Also, update BIOS and Video drivers both.

Comment: so none worked on their own, but together: uninstalling drivers, restarting and switching USB ports, seem to have fixed it issue.

Comment: Were the Driver updates I suggested part of the solution along with restarting?

Comment: Open Control Panel, navigate to your mouse settings and then ensure your click speed is correct and 'Clicklock' is not checked. Let me know how you go.